# Stripping HTML via PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I have a function that creates an HTML form lines [View](https://gist.github.com/3321459) by placing the requested variables into the array to produce the following:

`<input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"\" id=\"name\" class=\"\"  />`

What I am trying to do now is create a way to edit the specific field via the same form as the add, but I am unsure how to get the current:

- name
- value
- class
- placeholder - set by dropdown box with an input field if "yes" is selected
- type - sets the input type

How could I extract this data?

My DB Structure is as below I was thinking I could have it so I have a row for each paramater and then the label and field row that I then edit with any changes.

[image]

I have tied the following:

```
$testLabel = $field_info->label;
$testPrint = preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",$testLabel);
$data['test'] = $testPrint;
```

Label = `<label for=\"name\">Name</label>\n`

This gave me `Name/n` but I am unsure how I could build a function to get the specific data I need and also set the dropdown boxes.

**$field_info:**

```
private function fieldInformation($id)
{
    $id = $this->uri->segment(4);

    $information = $this->form_model->showFieldInformation($id);

    return $information[0];
}
```

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @BlaineI have updated the question

Comment: Regexp needs more backslashes. Basicly a `\` but be backslashed to count as what you want it to be. Try `\\` in each case instead.

Comment: @RobinCastlin Can you show me an example?

Comment: `preg_replace("/\\([^\\)]+\\)/","",$testLabel);` might even be `preg_replace("/\\\\([^\\\\)]+\\\\)/","",$testLabel);` but probably not.

Comment: @RobinCastlin Still know luck is it even the right function to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codeiginter [Form Validation class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html) is what you need.

Using the functions there, you can prefield your forms with data from the database, whilst also ensuring validation on each field.

Comment: Could you do an example? I can't see how I could strip the specific values out using FV class